# How to add fields from different models in the same admin view?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a separate admin page entry where I can see fields that interest me from different models on the same page.

get_sensor_id is defined in a model called MountedSensor, separate from SensorViewTypeBackgroundInfo

```
@admin.register(SensorViewTypeBackgroundInfo)
class SensorViewBackground(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = SensorView
    fields = ('sensor_view_id', 'sensor_view_name')
    list_display = ('enum_name', 'info_id', 'get_sensor_id')
```

Currently, I get the following error:

The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'get_sensor_id', which is not
 a callable, an attribute of 'SensorViewBackground', or an attribute or method on 'app.SensorViewTypeBackgroundInfo'

Following some advice, I edited the code in models.py as follows

```
class SensorViewTypeBackgroundInfo(models.Model):
     info_id = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, null=True, related_name="unique_id", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column='sensor_id')
     enum_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

     def get_sensor_id(self, obj):
         return MountedSensor.objects.get(mounted_sensor_id)

class MountedSensor(models.Model):
     sensor_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
     mounted_sensor_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

And I am now getting the following error:

> TypeError: get_sensor_id() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'obj'

Answer (score 0):

If there is some relationship between your models, you could use [admin.TabularInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline).

**Edit:** You're talking about `list_displays` which means you need new columns on your list, right?
In that case you can try something like this:

```
@admin.register(SensorViewTypeBackgroundInfo)
class SensorViewBackground(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = SensorView
    fields = ('sensor_view_id', 'sensor_view_name')
    list_display = ('enum_name', 'info_id', 'get_sensor_id')

    def get_sensor_id(self, obj):
        # Here you could get the information you need from your another model
        return MountedSensor.objects.get(...).field
```

You can remove `get_sensor_id` method from `SensorViewTypeBackgroundInfo`.

Comment: The models are unrelated.

Comment: You can create custom methods on `SensorViewBackground` and reference them on `list_display`. For instance: 
`def get_sensor_id(self, obj): return MountedSensor.objects.get(...)`.

Comment: I edited the code, I still get errors, I edited the question with the new information

Comment: `def get_sensor_id(self, obj)` should be on `SensorViewBackground` class to be recognized by `list_displays`.

Comment: @Andrei I also edited my answer to give you a better example.

Comment: I still need to set the "obj" variable which I don't know how to do. I tried "return MountedSensor.objects.get(pk=mounted_sensor_id)" but mounted_sensor_id is set as a foreign key, not an integer and I don't know how to set the get_value method correctly

Comment: @Andrei this method with parameters `(self, obj)` should be on ModelAdmin instead of Model. That's the reason you got the error. Take a look at my example above.

Comment: I have moved it now but I still need a parameter for the ".objects.get(...)" part. I don't know what parameter to put, I tried ".objects.get(pk = mounted_sensor_id)" but it returns an error "'mounted_sensor_id' is not defined"

Comment: @Andrei the return is gonna be whatever you need. You said your models don't have relationship, so you need to find some query that matches you want. For instance, replace your return for `return 1` and you will see 1 for each line on the table.

Comment: so what would be a model example of .objects.get(...) in my case? As mentioned, mounted_sensor_id didn't seem to work. Would adding a foreign key help?

Comment: just read your edited comment now. I get that, but I don't want to replace it with a variable, I actually want a line for each sensor_id but not sure how to put that into a single variable that would work. Should I create a foreign key between sensor_id and something?

Comment: @Andrei I really don't know what kind of relationship your models should have. Tell us exactly that you need.